# How will the flow of execution of the given code will be? And also how will the go-routines will execute here?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

(New to concurrent programming)
Had a doubt about why is the flow of execution of goroutines a bit weird here?

Beginner to goroutines and channels stuff in golang.

```
func main() {
    // Set up the pipeline.
    c := gen(2, 3)
    out := sq(c)

    // Consume the output.
    fmt.Println(<-out) // 4
    fmt.Println(<-out) // 9
}

func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for n := range in {
            out <- n * n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func gen(nums ...int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range nums {
            out <- n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

Comment: Can someone please explain what will be the flow of execution here?

Comment: what exactly do you need? diagram?

Comment: brief desc: you take two numbers and make a _channel_ form it with `gen`. then you pass that channel to `sq` and `sq` read data from channel until it closed (actually it closed in `gen`). `sq` makes new channel pass there two element then close it. then you read two elements with `fmt`

Comment: A diagram explanation might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Hope it helps. It goroutine pipeline diagram. So there are three goroutines and two channels

Answer (score 2):

Once calls to `gen` and `sq` are finished there are 3 goroutines running concurrently. They pass data between with channels and therefore the execution produces the same results.

1. gen-inner
2. sq-inner
3. main

They always pass at least 2 pieces of information through and therefore run their code in the order below

1. gen-inner `out <- n` -2-> sq-inner `out <- n * n` -4-> main `println(<-out)`
2. gen-inner `out <- n` -3-> sq-inner `out <- n * n` -9-> main `println(<-out)`

There is also a third pass that may happen but it may be skipped as `main` goroutine ends.

3. gen-inner `close()` -close-> sq-inner `close(out)` -close->